# mongodb php finding a subobject and removing it, $inc other subobject

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb, database

I'm trying to delete the subobject 'apples' from my documents and update the 'fruitInventory' property, decrease by the amount of apples.

I'm confused on how to proceed, should I use dot notation or do a full text search for apples? I don't know if this matters but you can assume apples will always be in field 1.

```
// Document 1 
{
    "1": {
        "apples": 3,
        "fruitInventory": 21,
        "oranges": 12,
        "kiwis": 3,
        "lemons": 3
    },
    "2": {
        "bananas": 4,
        "fruitInventory": 12,
        "oranges": 8,
    },
    "_id": "1"
}

// Document 2
{
    "1": {
        "apples": 5,
        "fruitInventory": 10,
        "oranges": 2,
        "pears": 3
    },
    "2": {
        "bananas": 4,
        "fruitInventory": 6,
        "cherries": 2,
    },
    "_id": "2"
}
```

Result should be like this:

```
// Document 1 
{
    "1": {
        "fruitInventory": 18,
        "oranges": 12,
        "kiwis": 3,
        "lemons": "3"
    },
    "2": {
        "bananas": 4,
        "fruitInventory": 12,
        "oranges": 8,
    },
    "_id": "1"
}

// Document 2
{
    "1": {
        "fruitInventory": 5,
        "oranges": "2",
        "pears": "3"
    },
    "2": {
        "bananas": 4,
        "fruitInventory": 6,
        "cherries": 2,
    },
    "_id": "2"
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the MongoDB query language there is no way to update a document using information from the document. In other words, there is no way to increment one property with a value from another property. To be specific: there is no way to increment the `fruitInventory` by X where X is the value of the `apples` property as an atomic operation.

The way I would implement this, while avoiding races, is with two `findAndModify` operations (seen here in Mongo shell syntax):

```
var fruit = db.fruit.findAndModify({
 query: {locked: {$ne: true}, "1.apples": {$exists: true}},
 update: {$set: {locked: true}}
});

var fruitInventory = fruit["1"]["fruitInventory"];
var apples = fruit["1"]["apples"];

db.fruit.findAndModify({
  query: {"_id": fruit["_id"]},
  update: {
    $set: {"1.fruitInventory": fruitInventory + apples}, 
    $unset: {locked: false, "1.apples": true}
  }
});
```

What happens is this: first I find a document which is not locked (more on this later), and has an `1.apples` property. The document is returned and updated to get a `locked` property as a single atomic operation. Since the document now has a `locked` property it will not be found by the same query, so this query can be run multiple times in parallel without any risk of modifying the same document twice.

I then extract the `1.fruitInventory` and `1.apples`, to simplify the next expression.

The second `findAndModify` updates the `1.fruitInventory` property with the new sum, and unsets the `1.apples` property, as well as the `locked` property (to return the document to its previous, unlocked, state).

To update all documents you will have to run this code over and over again until the first `findAndModify` returns `null` (meaning there are no documents matching the query).

Answer (score 1):

Use $unset with a multi-update:

```
> db.whatever.update({}, {$unset : {"1.apples" : true}}, false, true)
```

On a higher-level note, you might want to use richer data types (e.g., ints should usually be stored as ints, unless there's a good reason for them not to be).

Comment: How do I find which document it's in?
Thanks for the note about the int, fixed that.

Comment: This doesn't increment the `fruitInventory` property so it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't allow you to modifier exist scheme of document.For this task you should to remove document (or element of set). and Insert new modified document(or element of set)